Determine the values of the real parameter $m$, so that the equation $x^4-2x^3+2mx-m^2=0$ admits four different real solutions.
the problem
Determine the values of the real parameter $m$, so that the equation $x^4-2x^3+2mx-m^2=0$ admits four different real solutions.
the idea
I tried applying the quadric formula and got that $Δ= 4x^2(x-1)^2$, which makes $m_{1,2}=x(2-x), x^2$
I don't know what i should do forward! Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

You can continue with your idea.
To get $4$ solutions in $x$ you need both $x^2=m$ and $x(2-x)=m$ to provide $2$ solutions each.
The first one requires $m>0$, and the second $m<1$, so you know already that $m$ is limited to $m\in(0,1)$.
But the problem ask for different solutions, so you need to prove additionally that $x^2=m$ and $x(2-x)=m$ solve to $4$ different values $\pm\sqrt{m}$ and $1\pm\sqrt{1-m}$, after a little calculation you'll find that only $m=0,1$ is problematic, but these values are already excluded.

Why are 0 and 1 excluded?

$x^2=0$ gives $x=0$ with multiplicity $2$ so only one root. same for $x(2-x)=1$ gives $x=1$ with multiplicity $2$. If we want $4$ distinct roots we have to exclude $0$ and $1$.

$$x^4-m^2+2mx-2x^3=(x^2+m)(x^2-m)-2x(x^2-m)=(x^2-m)(x^2-2x+m)$$
From the first factor $m\gt0$
From the second factor do determinants greater than or equal to 0 and so the solution set will become
$$m\in(0,1)$$

A misprints: $-2x(\ldots)$ instead of $-2m(\ldots)$

Also, for distinct solutions, as it seems that the question requires, the interval should be open

@vincenzotibullo corrected it, thanks for pointing out

@vincenzotibullo was distracted a little in between and so I mistook it for 4 real and not different real corrected it too..

@YashShrivastava thank you for your idea! I dont understand how you got to those results...can you be more explicit?

@ionelabuciu just do determinant greater than 0 for both the factors so that they both have 2 distinct real roots and if the factors have 2-2 distinct real roots their product which is also our given equation will have all those 4 distinct roots

@YashShrivastava Why cant m be 0 and why the second requires m<1 and not $m\leq 1$...

For distinct roots if m=0 or 1 two roots will be same and if m>1 then second equation will have no real roots so the given equation will not have 4 real roots let alone distinct @ionelabuciu
